# Want regex for accepting $,0-9,a-z,+,-,/,*?

Tags: regex

Want regex for accepting $,0-9,a-z,+,-,/,* ?
basically inputs like
example 1 -  $a + $b
   2 -  $a/5
   3 -  5 + 6

Comment: You should probably write one then - let us know if you have any problems.

Comment: i am not that good at writing regex thats why i need help !!! I tried /^[+-\*\/\d\.\$]+$/ but it only works for numeric

Comment: @user3391398 There's absolutely no problem with that. But still, show us what you've tried so far. Then we will be able to help you.

Comment: If you're looking to check if a string is a valid arithmetic expression, a regex will not help you.

Comment: @Ferruccio yes i want to check for valid arithmetic expression if regex is not the solution then what should i try sample input $a + $b, $a/5, 6-7*3 etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should match any of the specified characters and no others.

```
/^[$0-9a-z+\-\/*]+$/
```

**Note:** the '-' character needs to be escaped in selection groups like this since it generally signifies a range of possible characters (i.e. a-z or 0-9).

Comment: /* is taking as comment in Javascript code. Please help

Comment: You still need to put the regex expression in /.../: `/^[$0-9a-z+\-\/*]+$/`.  That shouldn't be recognized as a comment.

Comment: i interchanged * and + and it started working

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to validate arithmetic expressions, you will need to write a parser or use a parser generator to write one for you. Although, to be honest, the learning curve to most parser generators is such that, at least for simple expressions like this, it's usually simpler to write one by hand.

For a simple parser implementation for arithmetic expressions, I would recommend you google for the following terms:

1. recursive descent parser
2. shunting-yard algorithm

If you want to try the parser generator route, here are a few I'm aware of:

1. lex/yacc
2. GNU Bison
3. ANTLR
4. GOLD parsing system